# Skype message to open local video file

Tags: 7.0-nougat, skype

I'm using Skype on Android 7. I have stored a video locally on the phone on the location /storage/emulated/0/myvideo.mp4.

How can I send a skype message (from another device) so that on the above mentioned device the video is opened? That means I would like to send a message containing a hyperlink to /storage/emulated/0/myvideo.mp4 and when clicked on it the video should open.

Comment: How long is the video. According to the Skype documentation only videos of less than a minute can be shared: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34718

Comment: @Robert The video is 5min. Actually I don't want to send the video over skype. I just want to send a link to the video which is already locally stored on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Links to local files on your phone only work on your device, not on other devices. If you want to share your video you have to send it via Skype (if it is less than one minute) or upload it somewhere and then send the online link via Skype chat.

Only if the both phones are next to each other an app that uses local sharing can be used, but that does not work with Skype.

Comment: Let's assume the video is in the local storage of device A. Device B sends a skype message to device A to open this video. So when device A opens the link the video is played. Do you see what I want? ;)

Comment: @machinery What you want is clear, however you can only use what has been implemented in Skype. On Skype for desktop there are some workarounds to send a video as live stream instead of the stream of a webcam (that would be the closest solution to what you have asked), however those hacks are not possible on Android.